# How can StreamWriter WriteLine append instead of overwrite in Powershell

Tags: powershell, streamwriter

I am trying to get this StreamWriter WriteLine to append the text to the already existing file but it's overwriting it.

```
$inputFile = ".\input.txt"
$outputFile = ".\output.txt"

$reader = [io.StreamReader]::New($inputFile)
$writer = [io.StreamWriter]::New($outputFile)

while($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true) {
    $readerLine = $reader.Readline()
    if ($readerLine -like '#*') {
        # skip line if it starts with #
    } 
    elseif ($readerLine -like '') {
        # skip empty lines
    } 
    else {
        $writer.WriteLine($readerLine);
    }
}
$reader.Close();$reader.Dispose();
$writer.Close();$writer.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [StreamWriter Constructor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_), you need to enable append.

```
$writer = [io.StreamWriter]::New($outputFile, $true)
```

Comment: Thanks I did try adding $true and it wasn't working but I probably was doing something wrong.